# function to_number(bigint) does not exists

Tags: postgresql

How can we convert the below oracle query into Postgres?

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_CD AS EMPLOYEE_CD,
         EMPLOYEE_ID AS EMPLOYEE_ID,
         TO_NUMBER(COUNT (1)) AS CNT
    FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_CD, EMPLOYEE_ID
  HAVING COUNT (1) > 1;
```

Comment: Why are you convering a number to another number? If the question is only the casting, you can add `::integer`, `::numeric`, etc to the column, e.g. `mycolumn::integer`.

Comment: Can you share a query with high performance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to convert a number to a number (and this senseless in Oracle as well). So just remove the `to_number()` from your query:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_CD AS EMPLOYEE_CD,
         EMPLOYEE_ID AS EMPLOYEE_ID,
         COUNT (*)  AS CNT
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_CD, EMPLOYEE_ID
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;
```

---

It has been a long standing, but [nevertheless wrong](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2020/02/25/count-again-2/), myth that `count(1)` is faster than `count(*)`. In Postgres `count(1)` is actually [slower](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/19/whats-faster-count-or-count1/) than `count(*)`. So using `count(1)` never makes sense nor does it improve anything.